# How to implement Firestore data encryption?

Tags: firebase, encryption, google-cloud-firestore

I have actually one SPA in ReactJs + one mobile application in Flutter + one REST API developed with SailsJs running on a separate server. I managed user authentication with the secured session cookie generated by Firebase Authentication sent back by the API when we are login with valid information (id/password).

Now, I want to encrypt highly sensitive data (medicines, treatments, patients) in the Firestore database so no one can see the data in clear when an intrusion happens or with the basic admin access to the console for the production database.

1. Do I need to encrypt the data at the client-level considering the fact that the connection between the clients and the API server is over HTTPS? Or can I just encrypt the received body at the api-level before storing it in Firestore and decrypt the encrypted data at the GET endpoints?
2. My idea is to generate an encryption key with AES at the user registration and store it in another database from an European/French hosting company in order to avoid any risk with the US Cloud Act or whatever (user id from Firebase Authentication <-> encryption key). Is it a good idea? What other solution can I choose to securely store and use the encryption keys of my users?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to encrypt the data at the client-level considering the fact that the connection between the clients and the API server is over HTTPS? Or can I just encrypt the received body at the api-level before storing it in Firestore and decrypt the encrypted data at the GET endpoints?

If you encrypt/decrypt the data in your custom API, that API will need to have access to the encryption keys. While the chances are small, it *does* mean the keys could be taken from here, and then be used to compromise the data.

If you encrypt/decrypt the data in the client-side code, only that code will need access to those keys. If you then exchange the keys through some out-of-band mechanism, something that doesn't get stored on your servers along the way, there is no way for anyone with access to those servers to decrypt the data.

Comment: Thanks, so what do you think about my #2? If I choose your solution, then the keys will be requested from my store actions on the client side (for ReactJs). What difference does it makes if a person gets access to the client server instead of the API one? Anyway we'll need the Firebase session cookie to get the key so where is the problem?

Comment: You seem to propose storing the keys in another database, which would be he "out-of-bounds mechanism" I mention in my answer. By storing them in another cloud database, you susceptible when that cloud database gets hacked. For more stringent security the keys should only be permanently stored on the client.

Comment: Ok but I need to allow users to use the solution through multiple devices. If I don't store the tokens anywhere I don't understand how to achieve this goal... My base idea was to request the token with the Firebase auth cookie at login and store it in another cookie to be reused since the session is active.

Comment: You'd essentially send the key from device to device, through an alternate mechanism. That's out out-of-band (sorry, I mistyped it repeatedly) means: you're distributing the keys through a different mechanism than the data takes, so that malicious users don't automatically get everything they need to use the data if one of your mechanisms gets compromised.

Comment: So a solution would be distributing the key at the client-level without the API? But that does not fix my problem of storing the keys in a place if I need to allow my users to get this token whatever device there are using with the same account. The revised solution would be:

1- Create a new token at registration and store it in database 2 with user id.
2- Request the token at login in the client with the Firebase auth cookie returned by the API login route.
3- Storing that token in another cookie to be reused for further requests.
4- Clean that cookie as the Firebase one at logout.